# How to take data from merged cells and populate that data on to multiple rows

Tags: excel

I am using a spreadsheet at work that, for whatever reason, groups certain data in merged cells, like this:

[image]

Each of these numbers represents the name of a project.

However, my task would be much easier if each of these numbers appeared on their own rows, rather than in one merged cell together. For example, it would look like this:
[image]

(I use a lot of lookup formulas that don't work with merged cells). I would really rather not copy and paste hundreds upon hundreds of values in their own rows manually.

Any help on this is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can't you unmerge all cells and use the  "remove duplicates" button to remove all empty cells which are left afterwards?

Comment: I don't think it's a "merged" cell. I think it's a lot of numbers in 1 cell. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, yes, that's true. I believe the cell is not merged but rather just contains a lot of numbers.

Comment: Are they always five digits long?

Comment: they range between 3-5 digits long.

Comment: Is there any data in other columns that must match up with what's in this column?

Comment: There is, but I'm not using it. I just need the data from this column in order to do an informal lookup with data in other documents. I'll copy and paste this column out of its workbook and into other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that might work for you.

1. Highlight the cells you wan to get the codes from (e.g. `A1:A10`)
2. Press `CTRL` + `H`
3. In `Find what:` press `CTRL` + `J`
4. In `Replace with:` type * (i.e an asterix)

Hopefully this replace line feeds with a `*`

Let's take cell `A1` as an example (after `*` added):

```
111111*
222222*
333333
```

Now add these formulas:

```
B1 = LEFT(A1,FIND("*", A1,1)-1)   // Result ~~> 111111
C1 = MID(A1,LEN(B1)+2,FIND("*",A1,LEN(B1)+2)-FIND("*",A1,1)-1)   // Result ~~> 222222
D1 = RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",A1,LEN(B1)+2)   // Result ~~> 333333
```

This gets the data into single cells.

Comment: This can be done using Data -> text to Columns, and using alt-010 as a delimiter. But I believe OP wants the data in a single column

Comment: Perfect. That sounds much easier. Please add an answer.

Comment: For some reason, the asteriks were not added, and therefore your formulas didn't work. Do the numbers need spaces between them in order to work? These don't have spaces between them. Your instructions were clear but they just didn't work.

Comment: Cybernetic nomad - it's ok if the data doesn't end up in a single column. If I have to copy and paste that additional column data below, it'll still be much faster than copying and pasting the data on new rows.

Comment: Your data may have spaces between numbers? You may need to experiment. In my formulas I assume the data has been added to a new line using alt + enter on the cell